Range of (dual) Radon transform on the manifold of affine hyperplanes
Let $\overline{\mathbb{P}}^{n-1}$ denote the manifold of affine hyperplanes in $\mathbb{R}^n$. Let $S(\overline{\mathbb{P}}^{n-1})$ denote the space of Schwartz functions (infinitely smooth with rapid decay of all derivatives).
Let
$$R^*\colon S(\overline{\mathbb{P}}^{n-1})\to C^\infty(\mathbb{R}^n)$$
denote the (dual) Radon transform defined (as usual) by
$$(R^*f)(x)=\int_{H\ni x}f(H)dH,$$
where one integrates with respect to the $O(n)$-invariant Haar measure of the set of hyperplanes containing point $x$.
What is known about the image of $R^*$? The same question with the Schwartz space $S(\overline{\mathbb{P}}^{n-1})$ is replaced with $L^p(\overline{\mathbb{P}}^{n-1})$?
